# remove absulte path from webpack output

Tags: reactjs, webpack, absolute-path

Well, I build my app using `webpack` in production mode, I have the output files containing absolute paths like :

```
E:/xxxx/xxxx/src/app/core/components/lib/RadioButtonGroupEntry.js
```

This is my `webpack` configuration:

```
resolve: {
    //When require, do not have to add these extensions to file's name
    extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx"],
},
//Render source-map file for final build

//output config
output: {
    path: buildPath,    //Path of output file
    filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js', //Name of output file
    publicPath: '/'
},

node: {
    fs: 'empty'
},
plugins: [
    //Minify the bundle
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production')
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            //supresses warnings, usually from module minification
            warnings: false
        }
    }),
    //Allows error warnings but does not stop compiling. Will remove when eslint is added
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "vendor",
        minChunks: Infinity,
    }),

    // new InlineManifestWebpackPlugin({
    //     name: 'webpackManifest'
    // }),
    new WebpackMd5Hash(),
    // new ManifestPlugin(),
    // new ChunkManifestPlugin({
    //     filename: "chunk-manifest.json",
    //     manifestVariable: "webpackManifest"
    // }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: 'src/www/index.ejs'}),
    //Transfer Files
    new TransferWebpackPlugin([{from: 'www'}], path.resolve(__dirname,'src'))]
```

I think my `webpack.config` is messed up and I would like some help to figure out what is wrong with it so that the absolute path will be removed.
Thanks.

Comment: do your src files have absolute path or require.resolve in them?

Comment: You can use `path.dirname(path)` for relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to configure the output path property of your webpack configuration object with path and the node `__dirname` global object, as this:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'yourBuildFolder')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (I use multiple entries) and solved it with `path.relative()`:

```js
{
  entry: {
    'head': [
      `./${path.relative(__dirname, 'my/source/path.js')}`,
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```